# Run-time permission and translucent overlay

Tags: android, overlay, android-permissions, user-permissions, android-8.0-oreo

I'm facing screen overlay issue on Android 8.0. Mentioned below are the permission which are mentioned in my manifest.xml file -

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

On Button click (button is inside the fragment), I'm checking if `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission is granted or not. If not granted I'm doing below stuff -

```
requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 5);
```

& in `onRequestPermissionsResult` callback if `PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED` & `requestCode == 5` I'm calling my logical part.

However, if I press either of the **Allow** or **Deny** buttons of permission popup, **I'm getting translucent overlay over entire device screen** & unless I'm not killing the app from background it's not getting removed. Also, the device back button is not working in this scenario.

This happens every time when I invoke the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission dialog & taking one of the actions.

If the permission is already granted app is working perfectly without any overlay issue.

My `minSdkVersion = 19` & `targetSdkVersion = 27`.

Also, there are **no Toast messages** present in my code.

I've tested the app in Android 7.0 & it is working fine on it. I'm getting this issue on Android 8.0 devices like Nexus 6P / Google Pixel devices.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This can be because of other applications too. Check for apps which are running with overlay permissions like whatsapp, close them.

Comment: @Dhananjay, I've tested this & it has no impact on my issue. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Try this I make two separate methods for permission check.

```
/**
 * this method request to permission asked.
 */
private void requestPermissions() {
    boolean shouldProvideRationale =
            ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

    if (shouldProvideRationale) {
    } else {
        Log.i("Error", "Requesting permission");
        // previously and checked "Never ask again".
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}

/**
 * this method check permission and return current state of permission need.
 */
private boolean checkPermissions() {
    int permissionState = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    return permissionState == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (grantResults.length <= 0) {
            // If user interaction was interrupted, the permission request is cancelled and you
            // receive empty arrays.
            Log.i("Error", "User interaction was cancelled.");
        } else if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Permission was granted. Kick off the process of building and connecting
            // GoogleApiClient.
            getCallDetails();
        } else {
        }
    }

}
```

then after checking in the main activity like this.

```
if (!checkPermissions()) {
    requestPermissions();
} else {
    getWrite();
}
```

Comment: I've everything that you've mentioned in my code. I've not mentioned it to keep the question simple. Thanks for your input.